# Query to Convert Varchar HH:MM to Integer Minutes in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having a table in SQL Server where there is a column name  `TimeSpent Datatype Varchar(25)`. It basically stores Time as `HH:MM` Format.
As per the requirement now i want that it gives me actual timespent in Minutes i.e. 01:00 gives me 60, 01:30 -> 90.
Please help me to write the query in SQL Server 2008 , so that will convert Varchar (HH:MM) into Minutes(integer).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT LTRIM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, TimeSpent)) 
  FROM yourtable
```

Given

```
| TIMESPENT |
-------------
|     00:12 |
|     01:05 |
|     10:00 |
```

Output:

```
| MINUTES |
-----------
|      12 |
|      65 |
|     600 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/69f2e/3)**

Comment: Getting Error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: @DharmendraSingh Please provide sample data on which you get this error

Comment: Sorry @Peter, the query is working fine. Its my mistake as in the table ,where i am executing the Query had 10 Million plus records and 2-3 rows had invalid HH:MM format which cause the problem. Thanks a lot

Comment: `LTRIM` will convert the nice numeric response of `DATEDIFF` into a string, which, if you try to sort on this value, will give you incorrect results.  Otherwise, +1.

Answer (score 2):

This will solve your issue. Please refer to [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/74159/1)

```
select cast(left(TimeSpent, charindex(':',TimeSpent,0)-1) as int)*60+
       cast(right(TimeSpent, len(TimeSpent)-charindex(':',TimeSpent, 0)) as int)
from test
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT top 1 (substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), TimeSpent, 108), 1, 2) * 60 + substring(CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), TimeSpent, 108), 4, 2)) as minutes  from test

Comment: Do you really think using string functions for time processing is an improvement over the accepted answer?