# Query to Convert Varchar HH:MM to Integer Minutes in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am having a table in MySQL Server where there is a column name StateStartTime and StateEndTime Datatype Varchar(100). It basically stores Time as HH:MM Format. As per the requirement now i it to gives me Minutes count i.e. 01:00 gives me 60, 01:30 -> 90. Please help me to write the query for MySQL, so that will convert Varchar (HH:MM) into Minutes(integer).

[This Topic have the same problem but I need a solution for MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15539782/query-to-convert-varchar-hhmm-to-integer-minutes-in-sql-server-2008)

```
SELECT LTRIM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, StateStartTime)) 
  FROM Time
```

Giving me error #1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the function [TIME_TO_SEC()](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-time_to_sec-function.php) and divide the result by 60.

Example:

`select TIME_TO_SEC(StateEndTime)/60 from table;`